# react-bootstrap reactjs overlay popover trigger on hover only

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working on react-bootstrap overlay popover control. I only want the popover message to trigger when the mouse pointer is hovering over the icon. When I click on the icon, I get the dialog modal but I also get the message which will not hide until I click again.

Here is my jsx code

```
<OverlayTrigger 
  placement="top" 
  trigger="hover"
  overlay={(
    <Popover id="test">
      test message
    </Popover>
  )}
>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

at first, I tried no trigger, still the click triggers the hover text. Next, I added trigger={'hover'},
thinking if I specify only hover as the trigger, but click is still working and activating the hover text.

How can I get only mouse hover to be the only trigger and not click? The click is reserved for onclick to bring up the modal.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

after reading react-bootstrap webpage, I added the working code

Comment: hello! I'm having the same issue and not finding it in the documentation. can you provide specifically what you did to prevent the tooltip appearing on click? I also just want it to appear on hover! 

Much apricated